# How to increase heap size in Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java-ee-6, jboss7.x

I'm using Jboss 7.1.1 in Domain mode. How to increase heap size? I see heap size tags in host.xml and domain.xml. where i can change the heap size?

Answer (score 3):

1) Go to $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf(or if you are running different than that name)

2) Go to the line where it says `"JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m`....."

3) Edit that line to your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

The configuration for standalone is in the configuration file: bin/appclient.conf.bat

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms64M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to configure JVM options in domain mode.

1 - configuration for all server of a server group

```
   <server-group name="main" profile="full"> 
    <jvm name="default">
    <heap size="256m" max-size="512m"/>
       <permgen max-size="256m"/>
    </jvm>
    ...
    </server-group>
```

`

2 - common configuration for all server of a host

```
<jvms>
  <jvm name="default">
    <heap size="64m" max-size="256m"/>
    <permgen size="256m" max-size="256m"/>
    <jvm-options>
      <option value="-server"/>
     </jvm-options>
    </jvm>
</jvms>
```

3 - override common configuration of one server

```
<server name="server1" group="main“> 
  <jvm name="default">
    <heap size="64m" max-size="256m"/>
  </jvm>
  ...
</server>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have mentioned the configuration changes needed for the **increase of heap size** in **Linux** environments.

Go to the following location and **edit** the following **file**.

```
bin/standalone.conf
```

**Search** for the following line,

```
JAVA_OPTS
```

and change it accordingly to suit your **heap size needs**

```
-Xms1303m: initial heap size in megabytes
-Xmx1303m: maximum heap size in megabytes

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M -XX:MaxHeapSize=2048M"
```

Finally after saving the work, **restart** the server.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this answer on the IBM site https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/where-do-i-increase-jvm-memory-jboss-eap-61